# Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred. Ticket System

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a ticket system, everything works fine except when I go onto a different account to test out what the ticket system looks like for the people using it, I try to react to the "Player Report", "Bug Report", etc... as seen in the code, it just says i am unable to use the buttons and then throws this error.

Full error:

```
    C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90
if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                         ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
at ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90:46)
at C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - Copy\Events\Ticket\initialTicket.js:86:24
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - Copy\Events\Ticket\initialTicket.js:79:9
at async Object.execute (C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - Copy\Events\Ticket\initialTicket.js:20:9) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
```

Ticket.js Code:

```
        const { MessageEmbed, CommandInteraction, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const { OPENTICKET } = require("../../Structures/config.json");

module.exports = {
name: "ticket",
description: "Setup your ticket",
permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
/**
 * 
 * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
 */
async execute(interaction) {
    const { guild } = interaction;

    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(
        guild.name + " | Ticketing System",
        guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true})
    )
    .setDescription(
        "Open a ticket to discuss any of the issues listed on the button."
    )
    .setColor("BLUE");

    const Buttons = new MessageActionRow();
    Buttons.addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("player")
        .setLabel("Player Report")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY")
        .setEmoji(""),
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("bug")
        .setLabel("Bug Report")
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setEmoji("✔"),
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("other")
        .setLabel("Other Report")
        .setStyle("SUCCESS")
        .setEmoji("❤"),
    );

    await guild.channels.cache
    .get(OPENTICKET)
    .send({ embeds: [Embed], components: [Buttons] });

interaction.reply({ content: "Done", ephemeral: true });
},
};
```

InitialTicket.js Code:

```
        const { ButtonInteraction, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Handlers/Schemas/Ticket");
const { PARENTID, EVERYONEID } = require("../../Structures/config.json");
const Ticket = require("../../Structures/Handlers/Schemas/Ticket");

module.exports = {
name: "interactionCreate",
/**
 * 
 * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction
 */
async execute(interaction) {
    if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
    const { guild, member, customId } = interaction;
    if (!["player", "bug", "other"].includes(customId)) return;

    const ID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;

    await guild.channels
    .create(`${customId + "-" + ID}`, {
    type: "GUILD_TEXT",
    parent: PARENTID,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: member.id,
            allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
        },
        {
            id: EVERYONEID,
            deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
        },
    ],
    })
    .then(async (channel) => {
        await DB.create({
            GuildID: guild.id,
            MemberID: member.id,
            TicketID: ID,
            ChannelID: channel.id,
            Closed: false,
            Locked: false,
            Type: customId,
        });

        const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(
            `${guild.name} | Ticket: ${ID}`,
            guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })
        )
        .setDescription(
            "Please wait patiently for a response from the Staff team, in the mean while, describe your issue in as much detail."
        )
        .setFooter("The buttons below are staff only buttons.");

        const Buttons = new MessageActionRow();
        Buttons.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("close")
            .setLabel("Save and close")
            .setStyle("PRIMARY")
            .setEmoji(""),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("lock")
            .setLabel("lock")
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setEmoji(""),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("unlock")
            .setLabel("unlock")
            .setStyle("SUCCESS")
            .setEmoji(""),
        );

    channel.send({
        embeds: [Embed],
        components: [Buttons],
    });
    await channel
    .send({ content: `${member} here is your ticket` })
    .then((m) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            m.delete().catch(() => {});
        }, 1 * 3000);
    
       interaction.reply({
        content: `${member} your ticket has been created: ${channel}`,
        ephemeral: true
    });

    });

});

},

};
```

If you need to see any other parts of the bot please just ask, any help is rlly appreciated.

Any questions feel free to ask and I will try answer them to the best of my ability.

I am somewhat new to JavaScript and Node.js so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

Are these executed from the same button press/same interaction? If so, then set the reply that happens second to `interaction.followUp()` or `interaction.editReply` (depending on whether you want a second message (followUp) or to edit the existing message (editReply)).